# How to install a SonarQube server with a remote database?

Tags: linux, database, windows, sonarqube

I am trying to install a SonarQube server on my Linux machine. I want to use a SonarQube database on my windows machine - a Microsoft SQL server instance.

How can I connect my SonarQube server to my SonarQube database?

Answer (score 2):

Open the file conf/sonar.properties and edit the properties `sonar.jdbc.url`, `sonar.jdbc.username` and `sonar.jdbc.password`.

Example:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:sqlserver://windowsmachine;databaseName=sonar
sonar.jdbc.username=yourLogin
sonar.jdbc.password=yourPassword
```

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/) can also help.

Comment: but I don'y have jdbc user I am able to login into db server using windows authentication, Can I user windows authentication here instead of jdbc user? if yes please let me know how?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Integrated security is documented in the link that I provided.